# Location data for Nuclear Power stations in France

Tags: data

As it says on the title, does anyone know a place I can look at and/or download location data for Nuclear power installations in France?  I believe it is well known data, but I cannot find it anywhere.

It's a very innocuous request, based on choosing where to buy a new pad in France and is nothing sinister.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://globalenergyobservatory.org/list.php?db=PowerPlants&type=Nuclear

Comment: Shouldn't prevailing wind direction be a factor too?

Comment: and plate tectonic movement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_tectonics

Comment: Let not forget ocean currents too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EDF website shows the location of all the French sites

http://energie.edf.com/nucleaire/carte-des-centrales-nucleaires-45738.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this come up recently, but for worldwide sites, and I found [this map](http://maptd.com/worldwide-map-of-nuclear-power-stations-and-earthquake-zones/), which had a link to a [google fusion table](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=579353).  You'll have to create the points yourself, but its all there!